# Given $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{3-x^2-y^2}$, find the linearization at $(1,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I don't even know where to begin with this problem. All of the research I do requires that you have an a value to plug into the linearization formula? Is there a method to find a? This is all the problem states. Any hints?

Comment: Is this a part of the other question?

Comment: Yes it is, this is a multi part question on a practice final exam. I am studying for a midterm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearization of a function about a point can be written like this

$$f(x,y) = f(1,1) + (x-1)\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x=1} + (y-1)\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{y=1} + \text{Higher Order Teams}$$

So the terms I've highlighted will form the linearisation - check out Taylor's series for multivariable functions to get more insight